# Zipping objects in an s3 bucket and then uploading the zip folder to the bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an s3 bucket with a folder which has many objects in it and I would like to write a python boto3 code which will zip those files and upload that zip file back into the bucket.

```
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

    my_bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)

    for file in my_bucket.objects.all():
        print(file)
```

This fetches the objects and file.key gives us the keys. Instead of downloading the files to a folder and then zipping that and sending it to S3 is there another way? if so can someone provide me a code for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for following up. I will mark this as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there another way?

Sadly there is not. You have to download the files, zip them, and re-upload to S3. To speed up this process, you can perform all operations on a good ec2 instance and use S3 gateway endpoint for fast exchange of files with s3.